# How to mark a jenkins build as unstable within a python script?

Tags: python, jenkins

I use "assert xy" to mark a build as failed or not:

[image: example]

How can I mark a jenkins job to be unstable within a "execute python script" build step?
Is there something simular like the "exit code to set build unstable" option of shell scripts?
[image: shell script example]

Comment: `sys.exit(your_exit_code_as_int)`

Comment: Hi Klaus, this is how to set an exit code. Fine, but which exit code marks a build as unstable? Every exit code I tried marks the build as failed. There seems to be no option for using exit codes to mark the build as unstable (like the option of shell scripts in the second screenshot).

Comment: You just have enter the exit code of **your choice** in the field and make the script exit with **that code**.

Comment: The field "Exit code to set build unstable" is not available for python scripts. I posted an image of the option of shell script - NOT python scripts.

Comment: Concatenating shell and python scripts doesnt work either. The shell script (as second script) isn't executed when the python scripts exists with a return code != 0